# WCF HTTPS working when accessed via browser but not code behind. asp.net jquery

Tags: wcf, https

can't find a solution for my problem. I have created a wcf and I'm consuming it from jquery on my asp.net page. When I deployed it using http:// its working fine but when I use https:// and changing the security mode to transport, im getting errors. But if i will just set the security mode to none, i can access it from browser. Can you please guide to figure it out? I'm deploying it to windows server 2003. Thanks!

```
 <system.serviceModel>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="QPServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />          
        </behavior>    
      </endpointBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>
    <services>      
      <service name="tService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="tServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="tService" />
      </service>   
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: when i set security mode="Transport", is says, Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Comment: and also im asking to enter windows credentials.

Comment: Did you setup an SSL service on the web server? See [Implementing SSL with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734679.aspx).

Comment: Not yet, i thought it is no need because both are residing in one location and folder. I will try to read this link. thanks David!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after several trial and error. i found a solution that allows the wcf configuration for both HTTP and HTTPS and the configuration below is the solution to my problem. thanks for answering my question.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                           multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="QPServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="QPService">        
    <!-- http and https        -->
    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="QPServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webBindingSecure" 
              contract="QPService"/>        
    <endpoint address="" 
              behaviorConfiguration="QPServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="webBinding" 
              contract="QPService" />

    <!--http
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="QPServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="QPService" />
    -->        
    <!--https        -->
    <endpoint address="" 
              behaviorConfiguration="QPServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webBindingSecure" 
              contract="QPService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBinding">
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="webBindingSecure">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the HTTPS is duplicated in your example? Should the second HTTPS be commented out or deleted?

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure your service for https on windows 7 machine do the following:

1.Open IIS. Create a new website by doing a right click on the sites folder and select Add new website.

2.Now the add new website popup comes up. enter the details and in the bindings section select Type to be https and the port would change to 443 and a SSL certificate dropdown is shown.

3.Select a certificate from the dropdown that is used to secure your communication channel for this website or applications in this website.

Once you perform the above steps you have created a website that listens on https. Now just host your application underthis web site and when you  try to browse the service in IE you should be able to see and access it.

NOTE: I see in your configuration that you have not specified the namespace of the service. You need to have a fully qualified name of your service and the serivce contract.

I have the above setup and now i have the following configuration thru which i can browse my WCF service over https:

```
<service name="Sample.SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="TransportSecurity">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="Sample.ISampleService">          
        </endpoint>
      </service>

<webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="test">
          <security mode="Transport"></security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

<behavior name="TransportSecurity">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
```